# how using mysql CAST in db_select

Tags: database

I want to try doing Mysql Casting in my query by `db_select` but face to error,

```
$q=db_select('node','n');
          $q->join('field_data_field_cinema_type', 'fct', 'fct.entity_id = n.nid');
          $q->condition('n.type',array('movie'),'IN');
          $q->condition('fct.field_cinema_type_tid',11095,'=');
          $q->condition('cast(n.nid AS SIGNED )',11517,'>'); // also $q->condition('cast(n.nid AS SIGNED INTEGER )',11517,'>');
          $q->fields('n',array('nid','type'));
          ym((string)$q);
     $res= $q->orderBy('nid')->execute()->rowCount();
```

and query string

```
SELECT n.nid AS nid, n.type AS type FROM {node} n INNER JOIN {field_data_field_cinema_type} fct ON fct.entity_id = n.nid WHERE (n.type IN (:db_condition_placeholder_0)) AND (fct.field_cinema_type_tid = :db_condition_placeholder_1) AND (castn.nidASSIGNEDINTEGER > :db_condition_placeholder_2)
```

**My question is how can I use `Mysql Casting` in db_select?Is that supported in db_select or I should use db_query on EntityQuery ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `where()` method for a `SelectQuery`:

```
...
$q->where('CAST(n.nid AS SIGNED) > :nid', array(':nid' => 11517));
...
```

So the choice is yours which type of query to use.